# How to get Ember to detect a checkbox on change along with a glimmer tracked?

Tags: ember.js, glimmer.js

In ember js version 3.2.6, how do we get a checkbox to do extra logic on value changed?

Example, I have a checkbox (a toggle true/false) for `updateServer`.
The existing code is using a `glimmer` `@tracked`  and this work fine for showing some instant UI modification as can be seen on the `application.hbs`.

```
Value of update server:
{{updateServer}}
```

But then I need to add some logic on value change, see `onCheckboxChange`. That function is called, but it seem the value of `updateServer` is not the one after click. It's the older one, before click. See picture.

How do I get the latest value of `updateServer`?

[image: The value of update server is not the latest ones]

application.js

```
import Controller from '@ember/controller';
import { tracked } from '@glimmer/tracking';
import { action } from '@ember/object';

export default class ApplicationController extends Controller {
  @tracked updateServer = false;

  @action
  onCheckboxChange() {
    //some extra logic
    console.log(`at controller, updateServer is: ${this.updateServer}`);
  }
}
```

application.hbs

```
{{page-title 'EmberSimple'}}

<label>
  <Input @type='checkbox' @checked={{this.updateServer}} {{on 'change' onCheckboxChange}}/>
  Update Server</label>
<br />
Value of update server:
{{updateServer}}
<br />
{{outlet}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One simple solution is to just not use `<Input` but a primitive `<input`. This could look like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" checked={{this.updateServer}} {{on "click" this.onCheckboxChange}} />
```

However then you manually need to assign the new value to the tracked property:

```js
@action
onCheckboxChange(event) {
  this.updateServer = event.target.checked;
  console.log(`at controller, updateServer is: ${this.updateServer}`);
}
```

Comment: The primitive input doesn't work well with the instant UI change `Value of update server: {{updateServer}}` . Capturing the `event.target.checked` also works with the non-primitive. I prefer to use the non primitive along with `event.target.checked` . Thanks!

Comment: the primitive *should* work with changes from JS side!